# Redirect Match. Remove Numbers from Url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Just in need of some assistance with some redirects.

I have the following url I need to remove the ending number from:

http://www.testsite.com/category/subactegory/this-product-name-12966.html

So it becomes:

http://www.testsite.com/category/subactegory/this-product-name.html

I have tried the following but cant quite crack it.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^-([0-9]+).html http://www.testsite.com/$1.html`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your regex is little incorrect. Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?)-([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1.html
```